# Core Data Error: Persistent store coordinator is not getting the File. It is the Phase appDelegate.Below the bolded phase has error.

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, core-data

In My Application

I have one sqlite file CoreDataBountyHunter.sqlite

I am using the Core Data Object Model to connect this sqlite file.

As it is the Basic application I have got the error before fetching the data or actual code part. I have got the error like Persistent store coordinator can not connect to file or Model.

1) visits the view will appear part
NSManagedObjectContext *moc=appDelegate.managedObjectContext. Part
from that it goes to the

2) Some code which shows File is Exists

3) then it goes to the Below code of persistent store coordinator from which it calls the Function of MANAGED OBJECT MODEL which is present at next code here...
After returning back to persistent coordinator in if condition it has got error and aborting so please help

-

```
//1--------
     (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator *)persistentStoreCoordinator
    {
        if (__persistentStoreCoordinator != nil)
        {
            return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
        }

        NSURL *storeURL=[[self applicationDocumentsDirectory] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"CoreDataBountyHunter.sqlite"];

        NSLog(@"%@",storeURL);
        NSError *error = nil;
        **__persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[self managedObjectModel]];
        if (![__persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:nil error:&error])**
        {
             Typical reasons for an error here include:
             * The persistent store is not accessible;
             * The schema for the persistent store is incompatible with current managed object model.
             Check the error message to determine what the actual problem was.

             [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption, [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES], NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption, nil];

             Lightweight migration will only work for a limited set of schema changes; consult "Core Data Model Versioning and Data Migration Programming Guide" for details.

             */
            NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
            **abort();** I have error at this place
        }    ``

        return __persistentStoreCoordinator;
    }


    enter code here
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (__managedObjectModel != nil)
    {
        return __managedObjectModel;
    }
    NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"CoreDataBountyHunter" withExtension:@"momd"];
    __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];    
    return __managedObjectModel;
}

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Actually it is a total mess with how Core data is working with different paths to read Write data so please explain also. Thanks Why I am getting the error at this place.
So, After visiting the MANAGED OBJECT MODEL CODE IT GOES TO THE PERSISTENT COORDINATOR SO AT THIS PLACE IT SHOULD HAVE SOME MESS...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any time If you change the .xcdamodel file then your application will crash surely.

Comment: Which basically means you have to delete the app from the Device / Simulator and install it again. Problem Solved.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try to this code in core data:

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {

    if (managedObjectModel != nil) {
        return managedObjectModel;
    }
    managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil] retain];    
    return managedObjectModel;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to shout...

What happens when you use the more usual

`+ (NSManagedObjectModel *)mergedModelFromBundles:(NSArray *)bundles`

as in

```
- (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel
{
    if (!__managedObjectModel)
    {
        __managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundle:nil] retain];
    }

    return __managedObjectModel;
}
```

Unless you have multiple models it's slightly cleaner

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion:
Whenever you want to make changes in the core data file then don' do it directly in the same file or version of core data. Best practice is to follow the Modal versions for core data. It will prevent the crashes and also It will be very helpful in case when your app is already in production.
For modal version, refer this link. For more description please research on Google.

[https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-core_data_modeling_tool/Articles/creating_new_version.html](http://ModalVersion)